# Backbone/Marionette decouple views from getting data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, fetch

I have "list of projects" in my application. Each project has name, description and list of members(name + surname).

It looks like I have to fetch list of projects(name, description, etc) and for each project fetch list of members. It means I have some levels of views and each level fetches collections and creates instance of another views/sub-views.

All collections are fetched  inside of views initialize methods and loaded asynchronously from REST service.

It means I can not be sure when exactly ListOfProjectView will be ready (because of sub-views) and I faced another problems...

**The question - How correctly use views?**
1) Is it normal if I fetch data inside of view or I should pass complete data to view? 
2) Is it right to create instance of view inside another view?

Comment: Not that it _exactly_ answers your question, just thought this might help you out: http://jsforallof.us/2014/10/17/backbone-series-handling-asynchronous-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching models on `initialize` forces you to fetch `async`, otherwise you run a race condition where the collection will be empty by the time you render the view.

I generally, instantiate my collection and fetch its models before instantiating a view. I handle the actual order of events by leveraging Promises. By default Backbone sync will implements `$.ajax()`. When you do a fetch, the fetch will return a jQuery Promise. So, my view creation cycle will look something like this:

```
var myView;
var options = {
  collection: new MyCollection  // Instantiate your collection
};
// the then function takes two callbacks, first for success and a second for failure
options.collection.fetch().then(function(){ 
  myView = new MyView(options)  // Your collection is a property of this options
                                // object. It is guaranteed to have returned from
                                // the fetch and should be full
  myView.render();
}, errorCallback);
```

Regarding your second issue, there's nothing wrong with handling views within views, if the sub-view is part of the view hierarchy. It's not the only way. But it is sensical, and in general, I have not run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Marionette (and you should be), then what you describe is the following:

ListOfProjects which is a CompositeView (or CollectionView), which itemView (childView) is a Project, which by itself is a CompositeView, which itemView is a Member.

The Marionette will render the views when the data is available, so assuming you have a plain REST api, it will do perform the following requests:

```
/projects
/projects/1/members
/projects/2/members 
...
/projects/N/members
```

The projects list will render after the first request is finished, and members of each project will render as soon as the collection was fetched.

If you want to optimize the number of network requests (if the number of projects is large), then you might want to include the members in the JSON for each project, and override the [parse method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) in order to take the members out and convert to the corresponding collections.